# How to create a Publisher which would emit an item only when requested?

Tags: project-reactor

I would like to bridge a non reactive api, which generates an item when requested, with a reactive Publisher. Basically whenever a subscriber will request and item from said publisher, that publisher will generate the item, but not before, since the operation is expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expensive item generation is synchronous and stateless, use `generate(Consumer<SynchronousSink>)`:

```
Flux<UUID> uuidFlux = Flux.generate(sink -> sink.next(UUID.randomUUID());
```

If it is synchronous and stateful, use the relevant overloads:

```
Flux<String> customUuidFlux = Flux.generate(AtomicLong::new, (indexState, sink) -> {
    sink.next("item#" + indexState.getAndIncrement() + "-" + UUID.randomUUID());
    return indexState;
});
```